# Show clear button in Search Bar when its activated

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Is there a way to display the clear button (x) in the search bar when its activated? It appears when we start to type but won't come when we just hit the search bar and not type anything.

Comment: Check `clearButtonMode` property.

Comment: @ToseefKhilji This will be activated only if there is anything in the search textfield. Changing this to always won't even do the trick

Comment: Just curious why you would want the clear button if there is no text to clear? That makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

in your viewDidLoad

```
 var textToSearch = "" {
    didSet {
        let textWithoutFirstSpace = textToSearch.dropFirst()
        // implement search functionality here
        print(String(textWithoutFirstSpace))
    }
  }

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       // after initializing  the search bar 
        searchBar.delegate = self
        
    }
```

then use the delegate functions

```
extension ViewController:UISearchBarDelegate {
  func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
        self.searchBar.searchTextField.text = " "
    }
  }

  func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchText == "" {
        self.searchBar.searchTextField.text = " "
    }
  }

  func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.searchBar.searchTextField.text = " "
    }
  }


  func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    if let text = searchBar.text {
        textToSearch = text
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Love this idea but the placeholder will go when we set it to that empty space string. Also, I want the X button only when I click on the Search bar. Is there any other way?

Comment: if this one now helpful ? edited